# Running multiple asyntasks

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have a task to fetch data from server at start if application. For purpose i am calling an api by asynctask for notification codes and parse data. The data can go upto 60000 notification codes.
For each notification code i have to call different apis to get data. After performing operation i need to again call an acknowledge api to tell server notification has been acknowledged. So next time when getting notification code it dont repeat.

So in the case i have to call approximately 60000 asynctask for operation and 60000 for acknowledgement. Do each operation for different api urls and then Acknowledge each operation for different url simultaneously

My app is working when notifications are below 1000 but for more than that notification it stucks.

Please anyone can guide what's the best way to implement this.

Comment: Have you tried kotlin + coroutines?  They are very light weight and should do what you want.

Comment: I am using java

Comment: You can do all in one asynctask.